# Debugger not active when compile with maven

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, maven, flash

here is my question :
When I build my swf by FlashBuilder, my debugger is active (access via context menu), and I got my logs in the flashlogs.txt.
BUT when I build my swf with maven (flexmojos-maven-plugin), even if I put `<debug>true</debug>` in the configuration, I hadn't any logs and can't active the debug in the flash application.

Any idea why ?

Informations :
I need to be able to access the debugger and have the trace in the flashlogs.txt without compiling and launching via FlashBuilder.
=> It's for some tester who don't have to access to the sources, just launching the application and testing it

Comment: Isn't Maven an automated Build process tool?  Why would the interactive debugger apply to that?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think Ben means, that he wants to compile swf in debug mode

Comment: @TimofeiDavydik Yes, it's what I want/need, but id doesn't T_T

Answer (score -2):

Once you built your swf with Maven, you need to deploy it on your web server.

```
Example: c:\java\tomcat\webapps\myapp (depending of your back-end)
```

Then in Flash Builder, in the Flex Build Path configuration for your project, you have to set the output folder to the target folder where you have your web server pick up the SWF you are building.

Set the Output folder URL to point to the context that launches the SWF and you should be good to go.

```
Example: http://localhost:8080/myapp
```

And of course be sure to compile with debug mode ;)

Comment: It's not what I ask.... the problem is that when I compile with the flexmojo-plugin with the debug at true, it's not working as when compiling with the FlashBuilder